# How to properly name gotoAndPlay function

Tags: flash

I wonder why did guys at Adobe/Macromedia choose function name:

gotoAndPlay();

and not:

goToAndPlay(); // *Capitalized To*

Is there a logical explanation?

Comment: I find this question rather odd. Are you implying programmers should be expected to use standardised, logical English for their variable names? We see things like widgetiseTheDongleDict all the time. A variable name is what it is.

Comment: I agree but I wanted opinions from others since my co-worker insist to use goToAndPlay version  in some Objective-c program and doesnt care about what millions of developers use ... I didnt know how to explain it to him .. Hope it will help! Big thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. **goto** is a word used in technical nomenclature: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto. The function name uses a [conflation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflation) of that *goto* and the English phrase *go to*.